# Como pegar o caminho de arquivos e inseri-lo numa tabela?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

Preciso criar uma declaração em MySQL que pegue todos os caminhos de arquivo dos arquivos de uma pasta específica e insira-os numa tabela do MySQL. Por exemplo, se minha pasta se chama `PastaTeste`, preciso que na minha tabela tenha algo assim:

```
C:\PastaTeste\SubPasta1\Arquivo1.pdf

C:\PastaTeste\SubPasta1\Arquivo2.pdf

C:\PastaTeste\SubPasta2\Arquivo3.pdf

C:\PastaTeste\SubPasta3\Arquivo4.pdf

C:\PastaTeste\SubPasta3\Arquivo5.pdf
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso com MySQL? Se não tiver, eu posso exportar uma lista de arquivos da minha `PastaTeste` pra Excel, por exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Com excel é possível realizar o que você precisa com o seguinte código VBA:

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub ListarArquivos()
     Dim objFSO As Object
     Dim objTopFolder As Object
     Dim strTopFolderName As String
     Range("A1").Value = "Arquivo"
     strTopFolderName = "C:\PastaTeste\\"
     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

     Call ListarRecursivo(objTopFolder, True)
     Columns.AutoFit
 End Sub

 Sub ListarRecursivo(objFolder As Object, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)
     Dim objFile As Object
     Dim objSubFolder As Object
     Dim NextRow As Long

     NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1

     For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
         Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Path & objFile.Name
         NextRow = NextRow + 1
     Next objFile

     If IncludeSubFolders Then
         For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
             Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
         Next objSubFolder
     End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não conheço alternativa para o xp_dirtree do Sql Server que permita importar directamente os nomes dos ficheiros. Para obter o mesmo resultado podes tentar da seguinte forma. Primeiro crias um ficheiro com a listagem da tua directoria. Por exemplo na linha de comandos do windows:

```
dir /s/b > lista_ficheiros.txt
```

Depois usas o comando LOAD DATA INFILE para carregar os ficheiros lidos para uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE ficheiros
  (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Ficheiro TEXT NOT NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE 'lista_ficheiros.txt' INTO TABLE ficheiros
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n%%\n' (Ficheiro);
```

Comment: Obrigado, isso funcionou perfeitamente pro que eu estava precisando!

Comment: Ainda bem que funcionou! :)